# Facebook JS sdk Oauth onload

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I trye to use Facebook JS SDK and I fell on a problem.

I want that after the page load, the user click on the FB button, and then,
if he is already logged I change location, 
if not,
it trigger the fb loggin popup

here is my code "

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<?php echo $action->appId; ?>', // App ID from the app dashboard
      status     : true,             // Check Facebook Login status
      cookie     : true,            // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true             // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {

         if (response.status === 'connected') {
            $(location).attr('href','nexPage.php');

        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            FB.login();
        } else {
            FB.login();
        }
    });
```

My problem come with the fact that the facebook authResponseChange trigger onload so if the user is already logged and just arrive on the page he is directly send to the next page, and I don't want that ! 
I want the user to see the page first, click, then login/or not and go to the next page
Does somebody have an idea how to do that ?

(and no click event possible cause after the user logged, FB reload the page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found !

put the status to false

```
FB.init({
      appId      : '<?php echo $action->appId; ?>', // App ID from the app dashboard
      status     : false,             // Check Facebook Login status
      cookie     : true,            // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true             // Look for social plugins on the page
    });
```

Sorry for disturb